# Get string from X509 Cert pfx file

Tags: c#, x509certificate, certutil

I want to get the x509 certificate as a string (certString)
so that I can use it like

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(certString));
```

to generate  a CertObject in Code.

I have tried around with certUtil but I dont know exactly which string I need.

Which string do I need to extract from the pfx data to be able to generate the X509 Certificate object in Code?

Comment: Something like this I think: `var certString = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\whateverpath.pfx"));`

Comment: I think that your question is not very clear. Please add more explanation. What exactly is the input? a PFX file on the file system?

Answer (score 12):

Here is the full code sample:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(@"c:\myCert.pfx", "password");
var certBytes = cert.RawData;
var certString = Convert.ToBase64String(certBytes);
```

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is converting it to byte[] then base64 string:

```
ConvertCertToBase64(cert.RawData);

private string ConvertCertToBase64(byte[] certRawData)
{
    return Convert.ToBase64String(certRawData);
}
```

Comment: What I mean is, how do I get certString from pfx file?

Comment: I assume you read the pfx from path. Then check my edited answer. Is that what you are looking for?